# Connect C++ signal to QML slot

Tags: c++, qt, qml, signals-slots

I'm trying to connect a C++ signal with a QML slot.

The C++ signal is called `userRegistered()` and the QML slot is called `userRegisteredQML()`.

In the C++ file, I have the following:

```
QQuickView view(QUrl::fromLocalFile("interface.qml"));

QObject *topLevel = view.rootContext();

connect(myClass, SIGNAL(userRegistered()), topLevel, SLOT(userRegisteredQML()));
```

And in the `interface.qml`, I have the slot `userRegisteredQML`:

```
function userRegisteredQML(){
    console.log("this is a test!");
}
```

The problem is that it does not show "this a test!". Therefore, I wanted to ask you if this is the proper way to connect a C++ signal to a QML slot.

Comment: Have you run qmake before build?

Comment: @273K I just did and nothing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expose your object to QML in C++:

```
topLevel->setContextProperty("myClass", myClass);
```

In QML, you can use Connections:

```
Connections {
    target: myClass 
    userRegistered: {
        // do something with it here
    }
}
```

Comment: what is  the variable `myClass` here?

Comment: @Arnold: you seem to have called your original instance as myClass, as the sender of your signal.

Comment: Pardon me, I thought it was a different variable. It gives me an error though: `main.cpp:262:29: error: no member named 'setContextProperty' in 'QObject'`.

Comment: @Arnold: that is because you specify your topLevel as QObject*, not QQmlContext* as it should be.

Comment: Now, I have a warning from `interface.qml` saying `ReferenceError: MyClass is not defined`.

Comment: Why don't you try loading your qml with the engine? Something like `QQmlApplicationEngine engine; engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/interface.qml")));`

Comment: Just did, still not working.

Comment: it shouldn't be capital-cased, first letter must be small, otherwise QmlEngine looks for a type

Comment: @Arnold: try `engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myClass", myClass);
 engine.load(QUrl::fromLocalFile("interface.qml"));` from here: https://blog.felgo.com/cross-platform-app-development/how-to-expose-a-qt-cpp-class-with-signals-and-slots-to-qml - Thanks, @Amfasis

Comment: @Arnold: did my update work for you in the end?

Answer (score 2):

QML js functions are not slots.
You should just create the signal in C++ and in QML you handle it with `on<signalName>`.
The solution depends on where exactly that signal exists.
If it is a `QML_ELEMENT` you would handle it inside the component instantiation in QML:

```
SomeTypeFromC++ {
    onUserRegistered: {
        function() {
            do_something();
        }
    }
}
```

If it is in an engine `rootContextProperty` You can use [Connections](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtqml-connections.html#details) QML type:

```
Connections {
    target: appCore // The name of the context property
    function onUserRegistered() {
        do_something();
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you should use the function notation in Connections : `function onUserRegistered() { doSomething(); }`
Context properties are also frowned upon now, better use Singleton or Singleton Instances

Comment: @GrecKo Thanks I added what you said.  
Wym by "Context properties are also frowned upon now"?

Comment: I edited your edit to fix it (:
About context properties, there's not much in the doc but https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-cppintegration-definetypes.html doesn't mention it. qmllint doesn't like it also I believe, and QML maintainers have also voiced that it should be avoided. It's the same as defining an id in a file and referring to it in another file.

Comment: I agree though In Python it is quite popular (and documented)... there was no  `qmlRegisterSingletoneType` until PySide 6.3.